# Magento 1.9, Newly Created Customer Attribute Will Not Save

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I am working on creating anew customer attribute. I have created the custom attribute using an upgrade installer script. The script successfully runs and creates the field. I can see the field in the Magento admin, however, I am unable to save the record.

```html
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->addAttribute("customer", "verifiedcustomer",  array(
    "type"     => "varchar",
    "backend"  => "",
    "label"    => "Verified Customer Completion",
    "input"    => "text",
    "source"   => "",
    "visible"  => true,
    "required" => false,
    "default" => "",
    "frontend" => "",
    "unique"     => false,
    "note"       => ""

 ));

$attribute   = Mage::getSingleton("eav/config")->getAttribute("customer", "verifiedcustomer");
$used_in_forms=array();
$used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_customer";
$attribute->setData("used_in_forms", $used_in_forms)
    ->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
    ->setData("is_system", 0)
    ->setData("is_user_defined", 1)
    ->setData("is_visible", 1)
    ->setData("sort_order", 200);
$attribute->save();

$installer->endSetup();
```

Other custom attribute values save correctly from the Magento admin but this newly created 'verified' customer will not save.

Below is the HTML generated on the Magento admin...
[image: 'verifiedcustomer' Custom Field]

```html
<tr>
  <td class="label"><label for="_accountverifiedcustomer">Verified Customer Completion</label></td>
  <td class="value">
    <input id="_accountverifiedcustomer" name="account[verifiedcustomer]" value="" class=" input-text" type="text"> </td>
</tr>
```

I'm looking for any ideas, and I appreciate the responses.

Answer (score 0):

So, apparently, Magento is no fond of the custom customer attribute ending with the word "customer". I changed the variable for the attribute to `verifiedprogram` instead of `verifiedcustomer` and now the attribute properly saves.

The final code below...

```html
<?php

$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->addAttribute("customer", "verifiedprogram",  array(
    "type"     => "varchar",
    "backend"  => "",
    "label"    => "Verified Customer Completion",
    "input"    => "text",
    "source"   => "",
    "visible"  => true,
    "required" => false,
    "default"  => "",
    "frontend" => "",
    "unique"   => false,
    "note"     => ""

 ));

$attribute   = Mage::getSingleton("eav/config")->getAttribute("customer", "verifiedprogram");
$used_in_forms=array();
$used_in_forms[]="adminhtml_customer";
$attribute->setData("used_in_forms", $used_in_forms)
    ->setData("is_used_for_customer_segment", true)
    ->setData("is_system", 0)
    ->setData("is_user_defined", 1)
    ->setData("is_visible", 1)
    ->setData("sort_order", 200);
$attribute->save();

$installer->endSetup();
```